# Get elements of SOAP response

Tags: java, soap, xml-parsing, saaj

When I send a `SOAP request` using `SAAJ API`, I would receive a large `SOAP response`, in which I need to search for some nodes.

I am using following code but it just show the name of first node of body (`HotelListResponse` which has many children) and I have noticed that the loop just iterates once, (as shown in commented section).

*In short: I need to know how to search for some nodes (preferably by their name) in a variable which its type is SOAPMessage. Thanks*

```
SOAPMessage sm = response;   //this is the response

sm.writeTo(System.out);    //response is shown successfully in console

SOAPBody ReBody = sm.getSOAPBody();
Iterator sentIt = ReBody.getChildElements(); //create an iterator on elements
int counter=0;

while(sentIt.hasNext())
{
  SOAPBodyElement sentSBE = (SOAPBodyElement)sentIt.next();
  Iterator sentIt2 = sentSBE.getChildElements();
  SOAPElement sentSE = (SOAPElement)sentIt2.next();


   String sentID = sentSE.getNodeName();  //result is HotelListResponse
   counter++;  
  //System.out.println("sentID:"+sentID);
}
System.out.println("counter"+counter); //result is 1
```

Comment: [SOAPBody](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPBody.html) implements the W3C DOM [Element](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html). Consider using [XPath](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html).

Comment: Could you post here a sample of your SOAP response?

Comment: BTW, if you want to iterate through the `HotelListResponse` children then you get a child iterator from `sentSE` and start a new loop there.

Comment: Agreed with @McDowell regarding XPath